Retrofit showing null values in imagepath
I am trying to display an image from an api but the gson response of retrofit shows "null" in place of image path.
Here below is my code of main activity:
lateinit var rvMain:RecyclerView
lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
    rvMain = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)


    rvMain.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
    rvMain.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        
    getAllData()


}

private fun getAllData() {



    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    var retroData = retrofit.getData()

    retroData.enqueue(object :Callback<List<MyDataItem>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call:Call<List<MyDataItem>>,
            response: retrofit2.Response<List<MyDataItem>>
        ) {
            var data = response.body()

            myAdapter = MyAdapter(baseContext, data as ArrayList<MyDataItem>)

            rvMain.adapter = myAdapter

            Log.d("data", data.toString())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>>, t: Throwable) {
            //Log.d("data", "!!! ERROR in getting data !!!")
            t.message?.let { Log.d("data", it) }
        }


    })

}

Below is my adapter code :
class MyAdapter(var con  :Context,val list:ArrayList):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
inner class ViewHolder(v : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    var img = v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.RV_Image)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    var view = LayoutInflater.from(con).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    
    Glide.with(con)
        .load(list[position].imagepath)
        .into(holder.img)


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.count()
}

}
Below is my data class code:
data class MyDataItem(
val __v: Int,
val _id: String,
val createdAt: String,
val image_mimetype: String,
val imagepath: String,
val imgae_filename: String,
val model_filename: String,
val model_mimetype: String,
val model_path: String,
val updatedAt: String
)

Hi , can you please share the log details so that I can see what is the problem you are facing.
